# How to handle smooth scrolling of ViewPager2 and horizontal recyclerView in the fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

So, I have a ViewPager2 with 4 fragments. Each fragment has a recyclerView with a horizontal scroll. Right now while I am scrolling the recyclerView items, the next fragment gets opened because of the swipe. How can I make it smoother so that scrolling recyclerView would not affect the tabs?
(Setting viewPager.isUserInputEnabled = false is not an option though)
What are your suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's the ready custom class for that)) Check it out, it solved my issue
https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/blob/master/ViewPager2/app/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/integration/testapp/NestedScrollableHost.kt